# Finding GCD of two numbers using recursion

Tags: python-2.7, recursion

I'm having a problem trying to implement the Euclidean algorithm for computing the GCD of two integers. The goal of the assignment is to use recursion and understand recursion. I'm a beginner so I'm still having trouble understanding this new concepts. I get Runtime error (I can't see specifically why or which error) using the following code:

```
def find_gcd(a,b):
    #write base condition
    if a == 0:
        return b
    else:
        a1 = max(a,b) - min(a,b) 
        b1 = min(a,b)
    return find_gcd(a1,b1)
#Take input
a, b = map(int, raw_input().split())
gcd = find_gcd(a,b)
print gcd
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: [Works for me.](https://ideone.com/dTmUgZ) What error are you seeing?

Comment: Please detail your input and output.  In particular, include the entire error message: line number, stack trace, etc.  I can't get this to fail, either, unless I supply invalid input.  In those cases, I get a descriptive error message.  What environment are you in that you don't see "why or which error"?